# python Изменить содержимое excel таблицы

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите как python'ом изменить содержимое excel таблицы. Наверное удобнее для этого будет использовать `pandas`. Но как с помощью него *изменить таблицу*, к примеру, переписать ячейки, я не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [функцией `append_df_to_excel()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046).

Например вы хотите перезаписать квадрат ячеек со стороной два элемента в Excel файле начиная со строки 5 (нумерацию начинаем с `0`) и столбца 3 (нумерацию начинаем с `0`). Записывать будем ячейки DataFrame с такими же "координатами" - т.е. с 5 по 6 строки и с 3-го по 4-й столбцы.

Пример:

```
In [32]: np.random.seed(0)

In [33]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10,10))).add_prefix('col_')

In [34]: df
Out[34]:
   col_0  col_1  col_2  col_3  col_4  col_5  col_6  col_7  col_8  col_9
0      5      0      3      3      7      9      3      5      2      4
1      7      6      8      8      1      6      7      7      8      1
2      5      9      8      9      4      3      0      3      5      0
3      2      3      8      1      3      3      3      7      0      1
4      9      9      0      4      7      3      2      7      2      0
5      0      4      5      5      6      8      4      1      4      9
6      8      1      1      7      9      9      3      6      7      2
7      0      3      5      9      4      4      6      4      4      3
8      4      4      8      4      3      7      5      5      0      1
9      5      9      3      0      5      0      1      2      4      2

In [35]: df.iloc[5:7, 3:5]
Out[35]:
   col_3  col_4
5      5      6
6      7      9

In [36]: df.to_excel(r'd:/temp/res.xlsx')

In [37]: append_df_to_excel(r'd:/temp/res.xlsx', df.iloc[5:7, 3:5] * 100, 
                            startrow=5+1, startcol=3+1, index=False, header=False)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а оформление при этом можно сохранить? Когда я делаю такое , то цветные ячейки становятся обычными

Comment: @dmitryklemenkov, насколько мне известно `openpyxl` это не поддерживает...